# Extract only file name From FileItem's name

Tags: java, servlets, apache-commons

In apache commons file uploading the uploaded files are available as FileItem objects.
If I get the name of such file item by using `fileitem.getName()` it returns the full path (ex: `C:\Test\test.txt`).

Is there any way to get only the file name.
What I actually need is to save the uploaded file as temp file using `File.createTempFile()`

but the name and extension of the temp file should be the same as the uploaded file rather than a random name(like `temp.tmp`)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try what [the docs say](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html#whole-path-from-IE)

> Why does FileItem.getName() return the whole path, and not just the
>   file name?
>
> Internet Explorer provides the entire path to the uploaded file and
>   not just the base file name. Since FileUpload provides exactly what
>   was supplied by the client (browser), you may want to remove this path
>   information in your application. You can do that using the following
>   method from Commons IO (which you already have, since it is used by
>   FileUpload).

```
String fileName = item.getName();
 if (fileName != null) {
     fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileName);
 }
```

Comment: @JoseK  is this suppose to replace filename with fileName?